# How to add xml files to my solution and get the file path as string

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio

I need to **add .xml files** (as test sheets) to my VB.NET quiz project, and then **reference them as string**.
Important to know the exact file path because in the file names are some properties like category, and test number, thoose the user sets in runtime before starting the quiz. This works fine, but my solution can't reach the files without the path. When I add the files as resource, the program reads the file as string instead of bring back only the path.
How can I do this?

Comment: Include them and in properties of each file set `Copy to Output Directory = Copy always` (or `Copy if newer)`.

Comment: Perhaps you could store the category, test number, and so on in the XML. Then it does not matter what the filenames are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

• To add files: <kbd>Right-click on Solution</kbd> - <kbd>Add</kbd> - <kbd>New Item...</kbd>

• Then go to the properties of each file (<kbd>Right-click on file</kbd> - <kbd>Properties</kbd> or select file and go to <kbd>Properties</kbd> pane) and select <kbd>Copy always</kbd> (or <kbd>Copy if newer</kbd>).

• You can also set properties for all files first by selecting them all in Solution Explorer and going to Properties.

#### UPDATE

Say, you have the following project structure:

[image: IMG1]

As you see, you have `consumers.xml` file in the solution's root folder and `addresses.xml` file in `data` subfolder. When you build app, the files' locations are retained as they were in solution explorer: `consumers.xml` will be in the same folder as your EXE file and `data` subfolder will be created with `addresses.xml` file in it.
Having such layout, you can use the following method to load them. In my example I use [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement) class.

**consumers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<consumers>
    <consumer>
        <name>Steve</name>
        <age>19</age>
    </consumer>
    <consumer>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <age>23</age>
    </consumer>
</consumers>
```

**addresses.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<addresses>
    <address>address1</address>
    <address>address2</address>
    <address>address3</address>
    <address>address4</address>
</addresses>
```

**C#**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Load consumers
    var consumers = XElement.Load("consumers.xml");
    // Load addresses
    var addresses = XElement.Load("data/addresses.xml");
    // Query XMLs
    foreach (var consumer in consumers.Elements("consumer"))
    {
        WriteLine($"Name: {consumer.Element("name").Value}, Age: {consumer.Element("age")}");
    }
    foreach (var address in addresses.Elements("address"))
    {
        WriteLine($"Address: {address.Value}");
    }
}
```

**VB**

```vb
Sub Main()
    '// Load consumers
    Dim consumers = XElement.Load("consumers.xml")
    '// Load addresses
    Dim addresses = XElement.Load("data/addresses.xml")
    '// Query XMLs
    For Each consumer In consumers.<consumer>
        WriteLine($"Name: {consumer.Element("name").Value}, Age: {consumer.Element("age")}")
    '// Or:
    '// WriteLine($"Name: {consumer.<name>(0).Value}, Age: {consumer.<age>(0).Value}")
    Next
    For Each address In addresses.<address>
        WriteLine($"Address: {address.Value}")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Now the files are added to my solution according your description. The main question is, how can I reference them as string? My reference is the following: **myPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "myFolder", myFileName & ".xml")** This string is directed to the **bin/Debug/myFolder** - folder. I would like something like this.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, now works it fine, but... Only in development environment. When I published my solution, the path won't working. So I like, that my installed program could to access the files